# Design correct relations of modes in Django

Tags: python, django, model

Please help to correct design the next things.
Need to have to teams list of stings which are connected to the list of companies. After this I want to use them to user model.
I did it in next way :

```
class CustomCompany(models.Model):

    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=30,
            default="None",
            unique=True
            )


class CustomTeam(models.Model):

    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    company_name = models.ForeignKey(CustomCompany,
            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
            related_name='company_name+',
            to_field='id',
            )


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    def _get_self_company(self):
        return self.company

    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(CustomCompany,
            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
            default='None',
            to_field='company_name',
            related_name='company'
            )
    team = models.ForeignKey(CustomTeam,
            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
            to_field='team_name',
            related_name='team_name+',
            limit_choices_to={"company_name__id":_get_self_company},
            )
```

Not sure if it's correct, but the main issue in it, that I should specify unique team model, but it shouldn't be.

> users.CustomUser.team: (fields.E311) 'CustomTeam.team_name' must set
>   unique=True because it is referenced by a foreign key.

Help please to understand how to correct do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`to_field`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field) parameter specifies which database column of the target table should be referenced by the foreign key column in the source table. Since whatever value is used in the the foreign key column must be able to unambiguously identify the target record, the value in the targe column must be guaranteed to be unique.

In other words, if two `CustomTeam`s have the same name, e.g. `"foo"`, how does a `CustomUser` instance with `"foo"` in its `team` column know which team it is associated with?

If you do not have a very particular reason to use another column, just omit the `to_field` parameter completely. Then, django will use the target model's auto-generated primary key column which is fine for almost all cases (it is unique, has an index for performant querying, etc.).

On top of that, if your app logic should not allow teams with identical names, it makes sense to make the `team_name` unique. I still wouldn't use it as a target for foreign keys though.

Answer (score 0):

The `to_field` parameter should point to the ID of a referenced table but in the team's table, `team_name` is not an ID. So if your CustomTeam table name is unique tag it with `unique=True`. If it's not just remove `to_field` and every thing works fine.